# sum elements of map by iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I want to sum the first four elements of `map` using `iterator` in **c++**.

```
map<int, string> numbers; //making object of map
numbers.insert(pair<int, string>(2,"two")); //inserting values into map
numbers.insert(pair<int, string>(3,"two")); //inserting values into map
numbers.insert(pair<int, string>(4,"two")); //inserting values into map
numbers.insert(pair<int, string>(7,"two")); //inserting values into map
numbers.insert(pair<int, string>(5,"two")); //inserting values into map
map<int, string>::iterator it;
it=numbers.begin();
for( ;it!=numbers.begin()+4; it++){ //problem is here and in body

}
```

Comment: Your code incurs a lot of copying. There's a completely unnecessary conversion from your pair to the map's `value_type`.  Why not `numbers.emplace(2, "two")`?

Comment: And what *is* the problem you're having? Just saying "problem is here" without telling us what the problem is doesn't tell us much. Do you have build errors? Runtime errors? Unexpected results? Is the problem that you don't know how to do the additions? You don't know if the loop is okay? Something else entirely?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::accumulate` from the `<algorithm>` header:

```
std::accumulate(it, std::next(it,4), 0, 
                [](const auto& a, const auto& b){return a + b.first;});
```

Comment: I believe std::accumulate is in the `numeric` header

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `+` for iterators. It only makes sense for random access iterators, but there is no reason to restrict yourself arbitrarily (and in fact it means your code doesn't work because map iterators aren't random-access). Instead, use the facilities provided by `<iterator>`:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>

// ...

assert(numbers.size() >= 4);

for (auto it = numbers.begin(), e = std::next(it, 4); it != e; ++it)
{                            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    acc += it->first;
}
```

The iterator arithmators `next`/`prev` and `advance` work for all iterators, and they dispatch internally to the most efficient operation. E.g. `advance(it, n)` performs `it += n` for random access iterators, and a loop otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of c++11, and if I understood what you want to sum, you could do :

```
std::map<int, std::string> numbers = {
  {2,"two"},
  {3,"two"},
  {4,"two"},
  {7,"two"},
  {5,"two"}
}; //Better initialisation
std::string sum = "";

for(auto it = std::begin(numbers); it != std::next(std::begin(numbers),4); ++it)
{
  sum += it->second;
}
```